# I can't find what Im missing in the code so the map updates

Tags: dictionary, netlogo

I'm creating a netlogo model to study the effects on an existing landscape of urban expansion, based on a projection for 5 years, 1o years and 15 years... I tried before coding it in a simpler model that is not based on a map and it worked perfectly, but when trying to incorporate it to the version that uses the map then the different projections dont update and I cant find what I am naming incorrectly... perhaps somebody can?

What I first wrote in the simpler version of the model was: (cobertura-urbana is a chooser)

```
patches-own 
[tipoDeUso]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; SETUP ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  ca
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks

end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; SETUP PROCEDURES ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor yellow]
  ask n-of 250 patches [set pcolor orange]
  ask n-of 350 patches [set pcolor lime]
  ask n-of 450 patches with [pycor > 1] [ set pcolor green ]
  ask n-of 150 patches with [pxcor >= round (max-pxcor / 2) and pycor < 0][set pcolor grey ]
  ask n-of 150 patches with [pycor < 1 and pxcor > 0] [set pcolor lime]
  ask n-of 25 patches with [ pxcor = 3] [set pcolor blue]

  ask patches [initTipoDeUso]
  initEscenarioCoberturaUrbana
  ask patches [actualizarColor]
end

to initTipoDeUso
  if pcolor = grey [ set tipoDeUso "Urbano"]
  if pcolor = yellow [ set tipoDeUso "AgriculturaTemporal"]
  if pcolor = lime [ set tipoDeUso "AgriculturaRiego"]
  if pcolor = orange [ set tipoDeUso "Pastizal"]
  if pcolor = green [ set tipoDeUso "Bosque" ]
  if pcolor = blue [ set tipoDeUso "CuerposDeAgua"]
end
 
to initEscenarioCoberturaUrbana
  if cobertura-urbana = "proyeccion-5" [
    ask patches with [tipoDeUso = "Urbano" and any? neighbors4 with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" or tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"]][
      ask patches in-radius 1 [
        if random-float 1.00 <= 0.044 [
          set tipoDeUso "Urbano"
  ]]]]
  
  if cobertura-urbana = "proyeccion-10" [
    ask patches with [tipoDeUso = "Urbano" and any? neighbors4 with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" or tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"]][
      ask patches in-radius 1 [
        if random-float 1.00 <= 0.088 [
          set tipoDeUso "Urbano"
  ]]]]
  
  if cobertura-urbana = "proyeccion-15" [
    ask patches with [tipoDeUso = "Urbano" and any? neighbors4 with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" or tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"]][
      ask patches in-radius 1 [
        if random-float 1.00 <= 0.132 [
          set tipoDeUso "Urbano"
  ]]]]
end

to actualizarColor
  if tipoDeUso = "Urbano"              [ set pcolor grey ]
  if tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" [ set pcolor yellow ]
  if tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego"    [ set pcolor lime  ]
  if tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"            [ set pcolor orange ]
  if tipoDeUso = "Bosque"              [ set pcolor green ]
  if tipoDeUso = "CuerposDeAgua"       [ set pcolor blue ]
end
```

and then what I wrote in the other model that includes the actual map, is:

```
extensions [ gis ]

patches-own [
  TipoRaster
  TipoDeUso ; Uso de suelo
]

globals [
raster-dataset
]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; SETUP ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  ca
  cargarMapa
  reset-ticks
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; PROCESOS SETUP ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to cargarMapa ;usa el mapa de uso de suelo elaborado por Urrutia-cardenas (2019)
  set raster-dataset gis:load-dataset "/home/lorena/Documents/UNAM/Tesis/versiones de corrección/mapa_raster_final.asc"
  gis:set-world-envelope ( gis:envelope-of raster-dataset )
  gis:apply-raster raster-dataset TipoRaster
  ask patches [initTipoDeUso]
  initEscenarioCoberturaUrbana
  ask patches [actualizarColor]
end

to initTipoDeUso
  if tipoRaster = 0 [ set tipoDeUso "Nada" set pcolor black ] 
  if tipoRaster = 1 [ set tipoDeUso "Urbano" set pcolor gray]
  if tipoRaster = 2 [ set tipoDeUso "AgriculturaTemporal" set pcolor yellow]
  if tipoRaster = 3 [ set tipoDeUso "AgriculturaRiego" set pcolor lime ]
  if tipoRaster = 4 [ set tipoDeUso "Pastizal" set pcolor orange ]
  if tipoRaster = 5 [ set tipoDeUso "Bosque" set pcolor green ]
  if tipoRaster = 6 [ set tipoDeUso "CuerposDeAgua" set pcolor sky]
  if tipoRaster = 7 [ set tipoDeUso "Otros"]
end

to initEscenarioCoberturaUrbana
  if cobertura-urbana = "proyeccion-5" [
    ask patches with [tipoDeUso = "Urbano" and any? neighbors4 with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" or tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"]][
      ask patches in-radius 1 [
        if random-float 1.00 <= 0.044 [
          set tipoDeUso "Urbano"
  ]]]]
  
  if cobertura-urbana = "proyeccion-10" [
    ask patches with [tipoDeUso = "Urbano" and any? neighbors4 with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" or tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"]][
      ask patches in-radius 1 [
        if random-float 1.00 <= 0.088 [
          set tipoDeUso "Urbano"
  ]]]]
  
  if cobertura-urbana = "proyeccion-15" [
    ask patches with [tipoDeUso = "Urbano" and any? neighbors4 with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" or tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"]][
      ask patches in-radius 1 [
        if random-float 1.00 <= 0.132 [
          set tipoDeUso "Urbano"
  ]]]]
end

to actualizarColor
  if tipoDeUso = "Nada"                [ set pcolor black ]
  if tipoDeUso = "Urbano"              [ set pcolor gray  ]
  if tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" [ set pcolor yellow  ] 
  if tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego"    [ set pcolor lime  ]
  if tipoDeUso = "Pastizal"            [ set pcolor orange  ]
  if tipoDeUso = "Bosque"              [ set pcolor green  ]
  if tipoDeUso = "CuerposDeAgua"       [ set pcolor sky ]
  if tipoDeUso = "Otros"               [ set pcolor magenta + 1 ]
end
```

Comment: Is there an error message, or just unexpected behavior?

Comment: just unexpected behavior